# dokku preserve files generated during application runtime

Tags: linux, node.js, git, file, dokku

I'm using `dooku` to deploy `node.js` app on DigitalOcean, everything is fine, yet recently I have added some dynamic files in to system i.e user on registration can upload image file and got some stylesheets generated personally for him. everything is saved in `public/styles` forlder of application.

Now, as I understand, on each push dokku wipes out previous app and instantiate new based on pushed repo.  So on each push i'm loosing all user stylesheets and avatars. That looks like a pretty obvious problem, but how should I go around it?

Thx for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've made more research before posting this one. Those who interested in answer and stumbled upon this question - you need to make persistend volumes which means that you will have a "link" between folder with those files in your application directory and folder in filesystem of your server machine. And all of the writes\reads addressed to your app folder will go to persistent folder in filesystem instead. For details of how to do this on latest dokku please see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-properly-configure-persistent-volumes-on-dokku-with-rails